# ¿Cómo modificar un sitio web luego de ser publicado?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Estoy trabajando en algo sencillo que consta en mostrar discos de música, su duración, información etc usando ADO.Net y SQL Server pero quería saber como es que se haría el mantenimiento luedo de haberlo publicado.

Estuve leyendo algo de usar FTP pero tengo que seguir investigando, una de las funciones del sitio vendría a ser darle de alta, baja, modificación a los álbumes (eso solo lo podría hacer un administrador) pero para eso tendría que poner un login (es la única forma que se me ocurre) y ya que el administrador vendría a ser el único usuario me parece que quedaría mal que haya una barra para ingresar a la vista de cualquiera que visite el sitio.

Cualquier consejo es bienvenido, por cierto no sé si se pueden hacer este tipo de preguntas. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: crea una página `/login` o `/admin` (como en Wordpress) y según el rol del usuario (anónimo o administrador) decide si aparece el botón "editar" o no.

Comment: Hola, gracias, había pensado en eso si, voy a ver como puedo ponerlo en marcha, saludos.

Comment: porque pones como tag de la preguntas web-api? estas usando esta tecnologia? es asp.net mvc con lo cual programas?

Answer (score 1):

No veo que ftp tenga nada que ver con el planteo que realizas, ftp es un protocolo para acceder a carpetas remotas en un servidor, podrias quizas subir un deploy del sitio al servidor para actualizarlo, pero esto no tiene nada que ver con la seguridad del sitio.

No estoy muy seguro si es `asp.net` o `asp.net mvc` lo que usas para desarrollar, por el planteo que realizas deberias aplicar seguridad.

si se trata de asp.net podrias implementar `asp.net membership`

[Configurar una aplicación ASP.NET para utilizar la suscripción](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/6e9y4s5t(v=vs.100).aspx)

Fijate como se indica en el `web.config`

```
<authentication mode="Forms" >
```

con esto mas definircion del proveedor, puedes conectarte a la db para autenticarte, asp.net membership define una estructura de tablas para asignar usuario con roles.

Comment: Hola, gracias por la respuesta, es ASP.net pero por alguna razón cliquée mal y puse esa otra opción, bueno, voy a probar eso entonces, saludos.